# BizTalk 2010 Configuration Error : (0x80004002) No such interface supported

Tags: visual-studio-2010, single-sign-on, windows-server-2008, biztalk, biztalk-2010

We're currently installing BizTalk 2010 on our servers and during the BizTalk Configuration, I was halted due to the error "No such interface supported" in the Enterprise SSO part. What could be the cause of this issue? And how can we resolve this?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Can you verify that the configured SQL instance is correct and running? Also the user you are using to run the configuration should have the correct access rights on the SQL Server.

Comment: Is all the software supported, Windows included.  Is the SQL Server local or remote?

Comment: SQL instance is correct and running, the BizTalk Configuration was able to detect the instance and also the user has all the access it needs to run SQl Server. We have an exisiting BizTalk 2009 in the machine and we are trying to upgrade it to 2010 but this issue is halting us.

Comment: @Johns-305 Yes all software are supported. It is running in remote but I also tried to configure it locally but same issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, never seen this error, are you sure the prerequisites are met? Are you installing on a single box or multi server?

**single box installation **
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14033.how-to-install-and-configure-biztalk-server-2010-in-a-standalone-machine.aspx

Comment: This is on a multi-server. All prerequisites are met, we are using SQL 2008 and it is running on Windows Server 2008 R2. I also tried making this as a single box but the same issue occurred. I was able to install it on some of our servers and the only changes we made before this installation was to disable SSL and RC4.